# PDF Signature fails verification

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, sign

I'm using iTextSharp.LGPLv2 to sign PDF documents (The only available option for .Net Core right now).
I'm able to produce a signature but most readers reject it. You can download the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ns35fdi5tyq52cw/blank.bs.pdf?dl=0

Few important issues:

- Both Adobe Reader and Foxit reject the signature saying that "the document has been altered..."
- The signature uses subfilter of "adbe.pkcs7.detached". If changed to "ETSI.CAdES.detached", Foxit decides that the **signature is fine**. Reader does not.
- SHA256 is being used for all hashing purposes.
- Looks like the ByteRange is correctly set.
- By using openssl, I was able to verify that the signature is properly formatted and contains a valid PKCS1.5 padded buffer.

I'm kind of puzzled here and I'll be glad to hear any suggestions/hints/directions.

Comment: iText 7 works on .NET Core...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two errors in the signature:

- Mismatch in document hash:

  The SHA256 hash of the signed byte ranges is

  ```
  69CF153087670FC5D450FF23675C207BB9659A235A465202F5802ABED7BA7C21
  ```

  but your signature container claims it is

  ```
  93D5804C1A9A31B17F041DE79FB1CD598E1FCC7CDC2A37885CD0502D4FCBB5A6
  ```

  which explains why validators assume that the document has been altered.
- Mismatch in hash of signed attributes:

  The SHA256 hash of the signed attributes of the `SignerInfo` in your CMS signature container is

  ```
  C84C6600F5E11291AAD8240239B7DC09FC00BD6A9056B6BBF584E8D46C8CEBE5
  ```

  but the hash value in you SHA256withRSA signature value is

  ```
  93D5804C1A9A31B17F041DE79FB1CD598E1FCC7CDC2A37885CD0502D4FCBB5A6
  ```

  which would make validation fail even if the document hash (see above) would match.

  Incidentally this hash in the signature value is identical to your claimed (incorrect) document hash value.

The latter mismatch probably is caused by you signing the wrong data.

The former mismatch may be due because of some error in your code calculating the hash of the signed byte ranges, or it might be due to the signed data actually being manipulated.

To further analyze the problem, your signing code would be required.

PS: There also is at least one error in your certificate, it has a negative serial number.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that two (wrong) values are the same. should give me something to follow. May I ask, how did you retrieve the hashes?

Comment: Your clues were enough. It works as expected right now and all I have to say is "Thank You".

Comment: *"May I ask, how did you retrieve the hashes"* - the [PdfSignatureAnalyzer](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/PdfSignatureAnalyzer.java) utility (based on some other classes in the same project).